# whats wrong with my FFmpeg add overlay command in android

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

i am trying add image over   a video using ffmpeg lib. it show

> [NULL @ 0xb6dab000] Unable to find a suitable output format for
>   'ffmpeg '
>       ffmpeg : Invalid argument

```
String addimg[]={"ffmpeg", "-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"\"" +"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"\"" +"-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-c:a copy","\"" +output};
```

**LoadFFmpegLibrary**

```
public void LoadFFmpegLibrary()
{
    if(ffmpeg==null)
    {
        ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("ffmpef","Start to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                    Log.e("ffmpef","failed to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.e("ffmpef","load Successfully");
                    ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(addimg);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
            Log.e("ffmpef",e.toString());
        }

    }


}

public void ExcuteFfmpefLibrabry(String command[])
{

    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("ffmpef","Exaction Start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("ffmpef","failed to Excute Command");
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.e("ffmpef","Video Edited Successfully");
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.e("ffmpef",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any who can help me..i am runing this code in android phone

Answer (score 0):

I Have seen your Code and get to know that you are using Writing minds For FFMPEG in Android Right?

and i your erro also indicate that ffmpeg is invalid  argumnet means ffmpeg is not found in FFMPEG

when you pass commands to writing mind build

for example :

you pass command like : `String command[]={"ffmpeg","-i",inputpath,outputpath};`

then ffmpeg execute below code::-- `ffmpeg ffmpeg -i inputpath outputpath`

so ffmpef cant find argument named ffmpeg in thier build

so change you command

from

```
String addimg[]={"ffmpeg", "-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"\"" +"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"\"" +"-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-c:a copy","\"" +output};
```

to

```
String addimg[]={"-i", inputpath,"-i", imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" ,"-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-c:a copy",output};
```

Comment: Now The my command is      String addimg[]={"-i ", inputpath,"-i ", imagepath ,"-filter_complex "+"\""+"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'"+"\"" ,"-pix_fmt ", "yuv420p ", "-c:a copy ",output};      i am getting   error  "  Error splitting the argument list: Option not found"

Comment: Hello there I am an android application Developer . Looking fow a freelancer work. i can develop video editing apps using ffmepg, like collage video maker,  Mv Master, Cropper , trimmer, stickers on vide etc so if anyone wants to do let me know